# Why is this an error : "Encountered the symbol "/" "?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm compiling a collection of store procedures in SQL Developer for the Mac.  The code looks like this:

```
// ... some other code ....

END procedureX;

END thePackageBodyName;

/

show error

grant execute on thePackageBodyName to anotherName;

/

show error
```

SQLDev is reporting an error "Encountered the symbol "/" for the first slash.  If I remove the first slash, and everything below it, it compiles successfully:

```
// ... some other code ....

END procedureX;

END thePackageBodyName;
```

Why does the first slash cause an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/` is used in SQL*Plus. Since you're not compiling in SQL*Plus, remove these, and all should be fine.

More specifically: an `/` ends a PL/SQL block which can be anonymous or refer to a package/procedure/function/etc definition/declaration. The slash tells SQL*Plus to transmit what has been entered so far to the server and have it compiled. So, it's not part of the PL/SQL language and therefore not needed.

I assume that you have imported or copy-pasted the content of a file into SQL Developer. So break it up into the compilable pieces between the slashes and compile these.

Maybe (and this because I don't know about SQL Developer) there is an option or a possibility to run such files that were created with SQL*Plus in mind in SQL Developer as well.

Comment: +1: Beat me to it.  PLSQLDeveloper must have a setting by now to accept the character?