# Why is my initial SQL (Oracle) not accepted by Tableau?

Tags: sql, oracle, tableau-api

For a project I've been working on, I had to create 2 tables in Oracle using Tableau's Initial SQL window. I basically need to re-create them each time Tableau does an extract, so would have to drop and re-create them. Only using the 'DROP' statement works, but if the extract fails in the middle of it, then when it re-runs, the tables don't exist, thus it returns an error.

I tried to use the below code which works fine in SQL Developer, but Tableau doesn't seem to accept it.

```sql
--Searches and deletes table TABLEAU_LCC_LEAD_TIME if it exists
DECLARE
   does_not_exist EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (does_not_exist, -942);
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE TABLEAU_DOC_LEAD_TIMES';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN does_not_exist
   THEN
      NULL;
END;
/
```

Tableau returns this error

[image]

Would you know of any workaround for the "/" in Tableau Initial-SQL for Oracle?

Comment: Tableau Initial-SQL isn't using SQL*Plus, so it doesn't recognize the slash. Have you tried it without the slash? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964294/why-is-this-an-error-encountered-the-symbol

Comment: I did. I got another error after this.Because after this procedure I am creating a table, I get error "Encountered the symbol 'CREATE'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think use temporary table in Oracle. Not need re-created table. https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables

Comment: I tried to use temporary tables but then tableau returns nulls. It seems to recognize the table headers but does not return any values from the table. I used "CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE"